# pygame window not responding when runing program

Tags: pygame, window

i have been working on a pygame platformer and been trying to run it buy my python window just says not responding and then crashes is ther anything wrong with my code. Here is my code

link to my code: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1QRNYi2hd5RBhIa-EwKdxdRPUdxWHALon

Comment: I don't see any code.

Comment: If the operating system says that your pygame window is not responding, then it's likely you're not handling events, but we need a [mcve] to help.

Comment: Don't post links to your project, add the code (in the form of a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) directly to the question.

Comment: i cant really add the code because then i have to format it and it take forever to do

Comment: can u please give me any solution to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the top of your code:

```
done=False
while not done:
    #event handler
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            done=True
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to open a window, change it to red and then close it when the cross is pressed:

```
import pygame

#Initialize the game engine 
pygame.init()

red = (255, 0, 0)

#Set width and hight
size = [700, 500]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

#The caption on top of the window
pygame.display.set_caption("My game")

#Loop until the user clicks the button
done = False

#Manages how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#--------MAIN PROGRAM LOOP--------
while done == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): #User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #If user clicked close
            done = True

    screen.fill(red)

    pygame.display.flip()

    #Limit to 20 frames per second
    clock.tick(20)

#Exits window if the original loop is broken
pygame.quit()
```

I hope that this helps